# SSRS subreport visibility based on parameter length count

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

1. I'm very new to SSRS, I'm working on sub-report visibility based on expression which does count on the parameter when passed to the stored procedure.
2. The stored procedure creates report for "Branch managers" and "regional directors"  and "regional director " doesn't see some sub-report which is in the report for branch manager.
3. In the stored procedure, I have a column called "branch_code" where each branch has a code  eg SE001 ,SW237 .....
4. When I pass parameter SE it becomes visible to the "regional director", when I pass parameter SW001 it becomes visible to "Branch managers" And there is a parameter called `@branch`
5. I have two sub-report where i have written an expression on one of the sub-report which I don't want "Regional directors" to see,

   The expression counts the length of the branch code as

   ```
   =IIf(len(Parameters!branch.Value) = 2, True, False)
   ```
6. so, if @branch length is 2 ie "SE" it won't show the sub-report to the "Regional directors" but it will show to the "Branch managers", here "the parameter is "Branch".
7. Now I want to do the opposite of it to another sub report where it should say when the parameter count is equals to 2 show the report else don't show. How do i achieve it.
8. I have tried with the expression

   ```
   =IIf(len(Parameters!branch.Value) = 2, False, True)
   ```

   but it didn't work. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ideally it should work, could you post some screenshot of your report/subreport.

Also how about you try with your first expression for "Regional Director", does it hide for it and show for "Branch manager"

Comment: @AnkUser Thanks, I have managed to bring back the sub report to the "Region director" but its only showing 3 pages. My sub report is restricted to only 3 pages.Any help on this?